# MEAN.IO Slack.js error

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

I've installed MEAN.IO as in the instructions here: http://mean.io/#!/docs

Along the lines I did see some errors in the installation process and I had to manually install grunt-cli globally.

When I create a testapp and run grunt then this is my output:

```
MEAN:~/testApp$ grunt
Running "clean:0" (clean) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

   packages/slack/server/routes/slack.js
      2 |var posts = require("../controllers/posts");
                                                   ^ Strings must use singlequote.
     11 |    });
              ^ Missing semicolon.
     11 |    });
              ^ Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
     11 |    });
              ^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
     22 |};
         ^ Expected '(end)' and instead saw '}'.
     14 |    app.get('/slack/all', auth.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next){
             ^ 'app' is not defined.
     14 |    app.get('/slack/all', auth.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next){
                                   ^ 'auth' is not defined.
     15 |        Slack.render('index', {
                 ^ 'Slack' is not defined.

>> 8 errors in 47 files
Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What's going wrong here?

For completeness here are my versions:

```
MEAN:~/testApp$ mean -v && npm -v && node -v
0.5.7
1.4.14
v0.10.29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very new to the MEAN.io framework and just install it and got the same error. The simplest way around it seems to be running the following in the root directory of the app.

mean package -d slack

then

mean package slack

Fixed it for me. Seems there was an update 6 hours ago.

Comment: Slack I see has now been removed from the install on github.

Answer (score 1):

Jay is correct. You can see this commit https://github.com/linnovate/mean/commit/433609f295dc4377882998e7e811c9a307bcbe89 that slack has been removed from the project.

You have 3 ways to correct the issue.

1. `git pull upstream master` to get the new updates
2. Do as Jay suggested by removing the slack package
3. Create a clean project with `mean init myApp`